# What pattern to use for watching when model is performing ajax request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `Item` model with the methods like `delete`, `rename` etc. These are async methods, so while one's being executed I'm showing spinner on my views. Since there are many async methods on the `Item` model, I'm forced to always do like this in my controller:

```
function delete() {
    isRequesting = true;
    item.delete().then(function() {
        isRequesting = false;
    }
}

function rename() {
    isRequesting = true;
    item.rename().then(function() {
        isRequesting = false;
    }
}
```

These `requesting=` statements clutter my code and also there's a possibility to forget to specify it.
I also have a singleton `fileNavigator` with many async methods, so here I used events to control requesting:

```
fileNavigator.on(FileNavigatorEvents.REQUESTING, function (event, requesting) {
    isRequesting = requesting;
});
```

And I no longer have to think about `isRequesting` when calling `fileNavigator`s async methods.
My question is whether there's any similar pattern I can use for my `Item` non-singleton instances?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using $resource? I would suggest Restangular and if you are using Restangular they have Request and Response Interceptors to fire off the broadcasts automatically to show and hide your Spinner.

Check out this: [restangular: is it possible to have a progress bar ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859505/restangular-is-it-possible-to-have-a-progress-bar/28940929#28940929)